# Is there an python solution for mapping a (pandas data frame) with (unique values of Split a string column)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame (**df**).
The Data frame contains a string column called: **supported_cpu**.
The (supported_cpu) data is a **string** type separated by a **comma**.
I want to use this data for the ML model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObcA6.png)

I had to get unique values for the column (supported_cpu). The output is a (**list**) of unique values.

```
def pars_string(df,col):
    #Separate the column from the string using split
    data=df[col].value_counts().reset_index()
    data['index']=data['index'].str.split(",")
    # Create a list including all of the items, which is separated by  column
    df_01=[]
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in data['index'][i]:
            df_01.append(j)
    # get unique value from sub_df
    list_01=list(set(df_01))
    # there are some leading or trailing spaces in the list_01 which need to be deleted to get unique value 
    list_02=[x.strip(' ') for x in list_01]
    # get unique value from list_02
    list_03=list(set(list_02))
    return(list_03)

supported_cpu_list = pars_string(df=df,col='supported_cpu')
```

**The output:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O06F7.png)

I want to **map this output to the data frame** to encode it for the ML model.

How could I store the output in the data frame? Note : Some row have a multi-value(more than one CPU)

**Input**:  string type separated by a column
**output**: I did not know what it should be.

**Input**:  string type separated by a column
**output**: I did not know what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend to anyone who's starting using *pandas* to read about [vectorization and thinking in terms of columns (aka Series)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/1642086). This is the way it was build and it is the way in which its supposed to be used.

And from what I understand (I may be wrong) is that you want to get unique values from `supported_cpu` column. So you could use the [Series methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#method-summary) on string to split that particular column, then flatten the resulting array using internal `chain

```py
from itertools import chain

df['supported_cpu'] = df['supported_cpu'].str.split(pat=',')

unique_vals = set(chain(*df['supported_cpus'].tolist()))
unique_vals = (item for item in unique_vals if item)
```

Comment: I have a unique value list; I want to map the unique value list to the data frame again instead of a multi-value string column.

Comment: Then you can only use the first line, which splits the column for every row

```df['supported_cpu'] = df['supported_cpu'].str.split(pat=',')```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-values in some rows should be parsed to single values for later ML model training. The list can be converted to dataframe simply by `pd.DataFrame(supported_cpu_list)`.

Comment: I need to connect it with the original data frame, not stand-alone data frame

Comment: ok. I may understand your problem incorrectly. How about you try this: First, split the multiple values in the original dataframe by @Hrimiuc Paul 'df['supported_cpu'] = df['supported_cpu'].str.split(pat=',')'. Then, split up the supported_cpu columns over multiple rows by 'df=df.explode('supported_cpu')'. Then...drop the duplicated cpu by 'df.drop_duplicates(subset = "supported_cpu")'...